# Centering an Actor horizontally and vertically causes the bounds to be wrong

Tags: animation, libgdx, scale, centering

I have a button in the center of my stage and want to scale it from the center as soon as the user starts to tap on it and then reset the scale as soon as he releases his finger.

This is the code I use:

```
private int size;
private Texture texture;
private Action scaleAction, scaleDownAction;

public PlayButtonActor(int x, int y, int size) {
    this.size = size;
    setBounds(x, y, size, size);
    this.texture = new Texture("data/play_button.png");
    this.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    setOrigin(size / 2, size / 2);

    final float finalSize = size;
    addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            event.handle();
            removeAction(scaleAction);
            scaleDownAction = Actions.parallel(
                    Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, 0.1f)
            );
            addAction(scaleDownAction);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            removeAction(scaleDownAction);
            scaleAction = Actions.parallel(
                    Actions.scaleTo(1.4f, 1.4f, 0.2f)
            );
            addAction(scaleAction);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    final float realSize = this.getScaleX() * size;
    batch.draw(this.texture, this.getX() - realSize / 2, this.getY() - realSize / 2, realSize, realSize);
}
```

This works as it successfully scales the button, however only the top right quadrant of the button is clickable.[image: Here is a graphic showing it.]

How can I make it so that the button scales from / to the center while the bounds of it are still correct all the time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try to set the origin every time you scale? Also, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604483/6242828

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the texture, but add the texture as an Image:

add(new Image(texture));
then scale the image. The clickable Area will always be the full Button size, independant from the image scaling.